# what is the appropriate return value of a function with an if condition

Tags: c++, return-type

what should the find() function return in this case

```
class Student{
private: 
    string name; 
    int age; 

public: 
    string get_name(){
        return name; 
    }
    int get_age(){
        return age;
    }
}

class list_of_student{
private:
    vector <Student> list;
public: 
    vector<Student> get_list(){
        return list; 
    }
    Student find_by_name(string name){
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            if(list.at(i).get_name == (name)){
                return list.at(i); 
            }
        }
        return ???
```

if there is no student with that name what should the function return

Comment: You could use a `std::optional<Student>`

Comment: Given the signature the only thing to do would be to throw an exception. Alternatively you could use `std::optional`. I.e. `std::optional<Student> find_by_name(string name){ ... }`

Comment: You should return a list of all students with that name, if none found then the list is empty.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what does std:: optional <student> return?

Comment: What about `{"", 0}` ? (Unless you allow newborns that don't have a name yet.)

Comment: @brah79 Just `return {};`. You need to `#include <optional>`, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: @john does this mean every time there is nothing to return I can just return {}?

Comment: @brah79 If your return type is `std::optional<...>` yes. But in general `return {};` means return a default constructed object of whatever type you are returning. There is no concept of 'nothing to return' in C++, `std::optional` is a normal C++ type which obeys all the normal C++ rules. But it is useful in the 'nothing to return' situation you describe.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in that loop, you **know** that `I` is a valid index into the vector, because you wrote it that way. There's no need to check it again, twice, with `list.at(i)`; just use `list[i]` in both places.

Comment: yes I changed it to list[ i ] thanks @PeteBecker

Answer (score 5):

Well, it shouldn't return any value of type `Student`, of course, which means that if you're determined to return something, the return *type* of the function shouldn't be `Student`.

You could have it crash the program with an assertion failure if no matching student is found; that would only be appropriate if the function is expected to be used in a way which makes that impossible. The classic C++ answer is "throw an exception", but C++ has such poor exception handling that few people actually take this approach. With either of these approaches, you wouldn't return *anything* if the search failed, so the return type would still be `Student`.

You could have it return a pointer to the student, or `nullptr` if no student was found. This is the normal C approach, and not uncommon in C++, but it makes it easy for calling code to "forget" to handle the potential failure, leading to a crash. It also forces you to return a reference to an already-existing object, and raises lifetime concerns.

Finally, you could return a `std::optional<Student>`, which would be similar to returning a pointer but would make the error checking/handling more explicit, and also allow returning a temporary.

EDIT: Klaus reminded me of another approach: Return `bool` to indicate whether the student was found, and actually *return* the `Student` (if found) via a reference parameter. This requires that `Student` be default-constructible and has even worse "forgot to handle the error" effects than the pointer approach, but it's one of the most simple and performant approaches.

EDIT: And *finally* finally, there's the approach where you make `Student` able to represent an "invalid Student", such as defining it as invalid if the `age` is negative. Don't do this. Please don't do this. Lots of people do this but please don't do this.

Comment: I was writing exactly this answer, but you type faster than me :)

Comment: You could also return `std::unique_ptr <Student>`, which would avoid a potential memory leak if the caller forgets to delete the object returned.

Comment: I guess I have to learn more about std::optional thanks guys

Comment: From my point of view an exception should be used if a really unexpected event occures. getting no search results seems not a reason for an exception, as it is simply not exceptional. I would prefer std::optional or a bool function with reference to an answer object. Matter of taste!

Comment: @Klaus Yes, though that viewpoint is one of the prime reasons for C++'s poor exception handling.

Comment: What do you mean with "poor exception handling"? Complicated to use? Generally switched on in the binary needs much more resources as really needed? Than yes :-)

Comment: @Klaus Oh, all of those, plus poor performance and makes surrounding code more brittle. I'll be honest -- I think that exception handling through nonlocal jumps is a failed experiment, not just in C++ but generally. But C++ has one of the worst exception handling designs.

Comment: Agree! The dirtiest thing I see is, that the compilers can't check if a tree of subcalls have a throw somewhere or not. noexcept simply did not help, because you can violate against without any warning nor error. App will terminate is not a expected solution. No need for further discussions I believe... :-)